# Javascript Email Id Validation with checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am looking to do a Javascript email Id & checkbox validation. The validation is only working for the checkbox but not for the email id. how to correct it please?

[codepen demo](https://codepen.io/bootstrap007/pen/gOaOKBm)

```
function Validate()  
{  
    var x=document.myform.email.value;  
    var atposition=x.indexOf("@");  
    var dotposition=x.lastIndexOf(".");  
    if (atposition<1 || dotposition<atposition+2 || dotposition+2>=x.length){  
        alert("Please enter a valid e-mail address");  
        return false;  
    }  
    return true;
}  


function Validate(){
   if(!validateForm()){
       alert("Terms & Conditions!");
       return false;
   }
   return true
}

function validateForm()
{
    var c=document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i<c.length; i++){
        if (c[i].type=='checkbox')
        {
            if (c[i].checked){return true}
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 // this function is called on form submit and checks the return values of both the email and checkbox function. if either of them are false, you will be alerted.
  function MainFunction(){
   if(!validateCheckBox() || !ValidateEmail()  ){
       return false;
   }
     alert("the form has been successfully submitted");
    return true
    }

// this function validates the email
function ValidateEmail()  
{  
var x=document.myform.email.value;  
var atposition=x.indexOf("@");  
var dotposition=x.lastIndexOf(".");  
if (atposition<1 || dotposition<atposition+2 || dotposition+2>=x.length){  
  alert("Please enter a valid e-mail address");  
  return false;  
  }  
  return true;
}  

// this function validates the checkbox
function validateCheckBox()
{
    var c=document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i<c.length; i++){
        if (c[i].type=='checkbox')
        {
            if (c[i].checked){return true}
        }
    }
     alert("Terms & Conditions!");
    return false;
}
//you had two of the same named function before. also you were only checking the return of one of the functions. Above checks the return values of both of the functions. Hope this helps
```

```html
<form name="myform" id="form_id"  method="post" onsubmit="return MainFunction();">
<input type="text" name="email" class="subscribe_email_nf" placeholder="Enter Your Email Id..."> <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="1">Accept Terms & Conditions<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit Form">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, Alex. Really Appreciate it. Is there a way to do the first Alert about "Enter Email" instead of "Terms & Conditions!". Currently the first alert is for the checkbox (Terms & Conditions!).

Comment: oh! Yeah... It's Working fine now. When i reorder the Syntax as - !ValidateEmail(),!ValidateForm()
THANKS ALEX.

Comment: No problem! Also, if you want to check for which values are missing, add if statements for each function individually inside of the main function.

Comment: Thank you very much, Alex. Really Appreciate it. :)